# Collation Error in same collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have 2 DBs

1 is the ERP DB and the other one is used for importing my data from 9 other location
Before the Collation was different for both the DBs but i changed the collation to same 
Now while i am running this command

```
use VDolphin
exec [s_importdatafromsalon_dts] '1','DOLPHINSHORTCUT'
use dolphinshortcut
```

this is the error i am getting

(0 row(s) affected)

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 2
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'DOLPHINSHORTCUT.dbo.s_vdr_Import_log'.
>   Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 7
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

(0 row(s) affected)

(61 row(s) affected)

(27 row(s) affected)

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
>   Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
>   Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

(25 row(s) affected)

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'Disctype'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'Disctype'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'Disctype'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'Disctype'.

(27 row(s) affected)

(25 row(s) affected)

(61 row(s) affected)

(27 row(s) affected)

(25 row(s) affected)

(27 row(s) affected)

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of the collations is case sensitive (the **_CS** suffix) and the other is case insensitive (the **_CI**) suffix.

You have to make them both the same.

Use `ALTER DATABASE <database> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS` or `ALTER DATABASE <database> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS`

Comment: Actually i already did that and the Collation for both the DBs are same now but still it is giving me this error

Comment: @user3808125 Nope - all you did was change the **default** collation which will only affect newly created columns that do not specify a specific collation at creation time.

Comment: actually i altered the whole database by this command with rollback